# Map variables through query

Tags: soql, variable

i want to get the value of the confList to the guaranteeSOQL but i get the error:
Variable does not exist: Replaced_Configuration__r

how can i overcome this?

```
list<Configuration__c> confList = [select id, name, Basket__r.id, Basket__r.Account__r.id, Replaced_Configuration__r.id  from Configuration__c where Basket__r.id = : basketId];
           
Guarantee__c guaranteeSOQL = [select id, name, g_Configuration__r.id from Guarantee__c where g_Configuration__r.id =: confList.Replaced_Configuration__r.id];
```

Thank you.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SFSE. Could you please [edit](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/325941/edit) your question to add detail of your Guarantee__c object's fields; specifically does it actually have a Configuration__c field that is a lookup, or does Configuration__c have a Guarantee__c lookup? (Basically which object is the parent and which the child)?

Comment: You need to reference an item from the confList, e.g. confList[0].Replaced_Configuration__r.id. Note this is necessarily the best way of doing it, what happens if confList is empty?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a basic error, where you are trying to access a list.
Try to go through apex documentation and see how does list or collections works in apex.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_collections.htm

```
list<Configuration__c> confList = [select id, name, Basket__r.id, Basket__r.Account__r.id, Replaced_Configuration__r.id  from Configuration__c where Basket__r.id = : basketId];

List<Id> lstReplacedConfig = new List<Id>();
for(Configuration__c objConfig : confList){
    lstReplacedConfig.add(objConfig.Replaced_Configuration__r.id);
}
           
if(!confList.isEmpty() && !lstReplacedConfig.isEmpty()){           
    List<Guarantee__c> lstGuaranteeSOQLList = [select id, name, g_Configuration__r.id from Guarantee__c where g_Configuration__r.id IN :lstReplacedConfig];
    // lstGuaranteeSOQLList take this and create a datastructure with map or whatever is required.

}
```

Comment: It was fixed that way, but what can i do in case of many confLists? how to assign each one to one guarantee record?

Comment: I have updated the answer.